# detect new tab is open with behat and mink PHP

Tags: php, bdd, behat, mink, browserstack

I have a behat test that clicks a button which usually opens a url in a new tab.

I can I test that a new tab has been opened after the button has been clicked?

this is the gherkin:

```
Scenario: Open document in a new tab
    Given I am a "Project Admin" for project "x"
    And   Project "x" has document type "orbitron" with editor "none"
    And   I create a new orbeon form "orbitron" for project "x" from fixture "OrbitronFilePicker.xhtml"
    Then  I visit the orbeon new content form for document type "orbitron" in project "x"
    And   I can see the "file-picker" control
    When  I enter a valid file picker reference "urn:isite:x:mickeyMouse"
    Then  I can see the card with "mickeyMouse" header
    When  I click "Open In New Tab" in the Dropdown Action Menu for "#section-1-control≡xf-383"
    Then  The document should open in a new tab
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a method/step that will switch to the new window? switchToWindow is called.

Comment: I havent yet no. I will look into switchToWindow now (I am very new to BDD's)

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this:

```
/**
 * @When /^The document should open in a new tab$/
 */    
public function documentShouldOpenInNewTab()
{
    $session     = $this->getSession();
    $windowNames = $session->getWindowNames();
    if(sizeof($windowNames) < 2){
        throw new \ErrorException("Expected to see at least 2 windows opened"); 
    }

    //You can even switch to that window
    $session->switchToWindow($windowNames[1]);
}
```

*NOTE:* Probably windows can open with some delay and in that case you need to wait for it:

```
    $ttw     = 40;
    while ((sizeof($session->getWindowNames()) < 2 && $ttw > 0) == true) {
        $session->wait(1000);
        $ttw--;
    }
```